# Wordpress: not stops or resets query

Tags: wordpress, while-loop

I am adding post thumbnail jquery slider to header part but it's resulting weird issue. It is somehow not ending while or stop query and so if I will go to single post or page it is keep displaying loop instead of page or post content.

I have tried two different query but none of them stopping to this weird issue.

**First Tried**

```
<?php
    query_posts( 'post_status=publish&orderby=rand' );      
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();              

    $title_attr = array(
        'title' => get_the_title(),
        'alt' => get_the_title(),
        'class' => get_the_title(),
    );
    echo '<a href="#post-'.get_the_ID().'" class="scroll theme">';
    the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail',$title_attr);
    echo '</a>';

endwhile; ?>
```

**Than Second Tried**

```
<?php
    $temp = $wp_query;
    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query();
    $wp_query->query('post_status=publish&orderby=rand');

    // The Loop
    if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();

    $title_attr = array(
        'title' => get_the_title(),
        'alt' => get_the_title(),
        'class' => get_the_title(),
    );
    echo '<a href="#post-'.get_the_ID().'" class="scroll theme">';
    the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail',$title_attr);
    echo '</a>';

endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();?>
```

None of these stopping to display loop ( all post like index page) in to single post or page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :)

I have added if (have_posts()) before while and end loop with wp_reset_query() and all good now. :)

So here is final code if anyone having same problem..

```
<?php
    query_posts( 'post_status=publish&orderby=rand' );      
    if ( have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post();          

    $title_attr = array(
        'title' => get_the_title(),
        'alt' => get_the_title(),
        'class' => get_the_title(),
    );
    echo '<a href="#post-'.get_the_ID().'" class="scroll theme">';
    the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail',$title_attr);
    echo '</a>';

endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

> I will go to single post or page it is keep displaying loop instead of page or post content...

That is because you are not passing it any parameters that would limit the query for single posts. Your query ( `$wp_query->query('post_status=publish&orderby=rand');` ) pulls all posts, all the time, and in random order. For single post display you need to pass it [a post or page parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters). You probably need to use [get_query_var()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) to check for 'p', 'page_id', or both. Something like this:

```
  $pid = get_query_var('p');
  if (!empty($pid)) {
    $qry = 'p='.$pid;
  } else { 
    $qry = 'post_status=publish&orderby=rand';
  }
  $wp_query->query($qry);
```

There are other possible solutions as well, like `is_single()`.

Also, WordPress uses the variable `$wp_query` so you should really pick another one instead of clobbering that one.

Comment: Thanks for reply,
My issue is it is displaying the way I want but it is affecting to single post and page where single.php or page.php should display them content but it is displaying in above loop format.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand your clarification and it doesn't sound at all like the problem you initially described.

Comment: It seems like it is not resting the query. I found solution will post for other user.. Thanks for your help